# Azure CDN connect custom domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have static website on azure storage, it's connected to azure cdn to have https, and i have my custom domain folla.com.pl I want this domain to point to https://companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net/ which is address of my website on azure cdn. I chose custom domain on cdn configuration site, it asks me to make dns mapping to verify ownership, so i make CNAME cdnverify.folla.com.pl to cdnveriy.companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net  and it get me to other window with custom doamin https config. And here's my problem, it get's stuck on second step
[image]

How I'm suppouse to configure another mapping to make it work, what i mean is to make folla.com.pl to point to https://companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net/ with https. I can't proivde what i already tried with my dns because it was a lot and i don't remember all of it. Also it's already second try and everytime after failure I have wait 8 hours for another try. Thanks in advance

This is my DNS config 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to add your custom domain `folla.com.pl` in the custom domains settings of Azure CDN endpoint. Before this step, you should have a CNAME record in the following format in the DNS zone.

[image]

When you turn **on** the **custom domain https**, you don't need to make a CNAME `cdnverify.folla.com.pl` to `cdnveriy.companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net`. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate#custom-domain-is-mapped-to-your-cdn-endpoint-by-a-cname-record).

> If that CNAME record still exists and does not contain the cdnverify
>   subdomain, the DigiCert CA uses it to automatically validate ownership
>   of your custom domain.

If the CNAME record entry contains the `cdnverify` subdomain, follow the rest of the instructions in this step.

DigiCert sends a verification email to the following email addresses. Verify that you can approve directly from one of the following addresses and read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate#custom-domain-is-not-mapped-to-your-cdn-endpoint).

```
admin@<your-domain-name.com>
administrator@<your-domain-name.com>
webmaster@<your-domain-name.com>
hostmaster@<your-domain-name.com>
postmaster@<your-domain-name.com>
```

Automatic validation typically takes a few hours. If you don’t see your domain validated in 24 hours, [open a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-troubleshooting-support-howto).

Comment: So to properly verify ownership on second step i should have cdnverify.folla.com.pl CNAME companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net ?

Comment: I also added pic of my dns config in question @nancy

Comment: It should have cdnverify.folla.com.pl CNAME cdnverify.companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net. In this step, DigiCert should  send a verification email to your email addresses. If you have not received any verification emails, I suggest removing cdnverify subdomain and re-enable the https for custom domain. For me, it will automatically enable the HTTPS features in a few hours.

Comment: Why do you have a extra CNAME record: `cdn.folla.com.pl`? It should have `folla.com.pl` CNAME `companywebsitecdn.azureedge.net`

Comment: My dns provider says i cant create CNAME to top level(folla.com.pl) domain, it can only apply to it's subdomains

Comment: Your previous answear means that I have to confirm sth on email? If it's like that then it's quite impossible, because i don't have email sertver yet pointing to my domain

Comment: I got it, actually, you should add subdomain `cdn.folla.com.pl` in the custom domains of cdn endpoint. Can you remove CNAME record `cdnverify.folla.com.pl` and try to enable HTTPS again? In this step, you don't need email confirmation.

Comment: Yeah sure, but then i'll reply in 8 hours, because every try like that blocks another for 8 hours

Comment: Sometimes, it just takes more than one hour for me. Good luck to you.

Comment: Didnt finish second step, just moved to hosting from this CDN and everything works fine. Thanks for your involvemnet anyway

Comment: Anyway, there is nothing to do with this question. If my reply could help other people in the future, please accept it to end this question. This method always could work on my side.